# An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator while submitting form using drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, state, dropdown

I am trying to submitting form in drupal 7 and I have dropdown field of states against country Australia
If I choose Australia country states options displayed below the country field.

My states lists:

```
public static $au_states = array(
"ACT" =>  "Australian Capital Territory",
"NSW" =>  "New South Wales",
"NT"  =>  "Northern Territory",
"QLD" =>  "Queensland",
"SA"  =>  "South Australia",
"TAS" =>  "Tasmania",
"VIC" =>  "Victoria",
"WA"  =>  "Western Australia",

 );
```

I am getting error of illegal choice has been detected when I select any options from states drop down.
But important thing to notice If I select state: "NT"  =>  "Northern Territory", in this case form is submitted successfully it does not show any error but except this state if I select any other states it display error.
I am stuck where is wrong.?
Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually is shown up when you add new input fields to your form or add/remove some of the options of the fields on the client-side (using javascript, outside Drupal mechanisms). In such cases, Drupal treats the modified form as insecure (sort of hacked by strangers) and refuses to process it.

As far as I understood, you have two input fields: a select input for the country and another for states. Is this your case? If yes, are you manipulating the options of the second input using javascript (to show states of the chosen country)? Again if yes, you have to use [Drupal Ajax API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7) on the country input to manipulate options of the states input in server-side, to inform Drupal you have changed the options of the field deliberately and it is not by strangers!